# How to convert a slightly misformed RFC822 string to a date?

Tags: swift, nsdateformatter, date-formatting, dateformatter

One of my sources contains date strings like this:

`Fri, 22 May 2020 22:49:06+5:30`

This looks like an [RFC 822 date](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5), except for the last timezone part.

I tried to convert this string to a date with code like this:

```
let str = "Fri, 22 May 2020 22:49:06+5:30"

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
formatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ssZ"

let date = formatter.date(from: str)
```

I tried all sorts of `dateFormat` strings, but the last line keeps returning nil.

Is there any way to convert this example string to a valid date by using a `DateFormatter`?

Comment: Could you take the part of the string after the "+" or "-" and make it conform - remove the ":" and left-pad it to four digits with "0"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the missing leading zero in the time zone part, there is no corresponding symbol.

A possible solution is to insert the missing zero with Regular Expression

```
let str = "Fri, 22 May 2020 22:49:06+5:30"
let adjustedString = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "([+-])(\\d:\\d{2})", with: "$10$2", options: .regularExpression)

let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
formatter.dateFormat = "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ssZ"

let date = formatter.date(from: adjustedString)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is brilliant!